# How to install ubuntu without formatting hdd

Tags: system-installation

I'm a Windows user.But for now I want to shift into ubuntu.

I have many personal data in my hdd.

I'm afraid,what if my hdd gets formatted and I loose all my data.

What can i do in in order to install ubuntu wihout loosing my windows parition?

Answer (score 1):

Check for the Wubi installation method. It can install Ubuntu on one of your spare drives (D: or E:) without formatting it. You can even install it on C:. 
I'm afraid this would work on Windows 7 and earlier only.
Not sure if I can paste external sites links here, you can just do a google on wubi installer for Ubuntu and you would get plenty of guides for it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a installation media most prefrebally usbFlash drive and then run that media on your machine . Try ubuntu with the live media and then install form inside the media if you have plenty of drive space where you have windows you can choose 
[install alongside windows] option 
if not then create a partition with enough at least (50 GB) free disk space and then install ubuntu on that drive .here 50GB is for smooth running of system I have allocated 100 GB space out of which only 15GB is used and I am using apps that would have cost me at least 40-50 GB of drive space with windows os.

[This](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop)  will help you with your installation

Answer (score 0):

Another option:
- Get a new disk; external, USB, USB-stick or anything else doesn't matter.
- Move your data onto it (with all the steps required)
- Install Ubuntu on the harddisk you have today.
- Install Virtualbox, create/install a Windows in there.
- Use your data from within both worlds while you get deeper into Ubuntu.

NOTE: If you get an equal type of disk, you might even be able to SWAP the disks, so your current becomes the external.

Comment: yeah this is good enough to try but isn't a usb stick too small to handle an operating system??

Comment: I'd suggest to move the **data** onto there, a 1TB disk isn't especially costly nowadays, even a 3TB is fair in price.  Still Ubuntu OR Windows **does** run from e.g. 30GB - unless you intend to install a load of games.

Comment: Yeah that will do :D

Comment: @ChinmayaB - A "Live USB" stick with Ubuntu need be only 4GB.  If the stick is bigger, the rest can be formatted as a "persistent" partition.

Answer (score 0):

You have (at least) 4 options:

1. You don't have to format your Windows partition(s), you only need to shrink them in order to free up some space and create a new partition for Ubuntu. The installer can do this for you with one click. Be sure to select the option to **install Ubuntu alongside** Windows. It's *recommended to backup* your data though. You will be able to select which OS to boot into when starting your computer.
2. You can also use [Wubi](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide) to install Ubuntu sort-of like a Windows application. This will have some performance drawback, but it's easy and safe. You can also remove it easily. Recommended if you only want to use Ubuntu occasionally and don't want a full install.
3. You can just use the installer as a [Live USB stick](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows), making no changes to your hard drive whatsoever. Recommended for just testing and very rare usage.
4. And of course, you can always buy a new hard drive for your Ubuntu install.